# Browserify, Error when concating files Cannot find module 'function e(t,n,r)

Tags: gulp, browserify

I'm using gulp-browserify. If I use them separately it works. But if I concating them, I get:

> Error: Cannot find module 'function e(t,n,r)

This is my gulp:

```
gulp.task("babel", function () {
  return gulp.src("src/**/*.js")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(browserify({
      transform:['babelify']
    }))
    .pipe(concat("all.js"))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

Versions:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.1",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.18",
    "karma-browserify": "^4.4.2",
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

You are concatenating multiple browserified files when what you really want to do is to browserify concatenated file

```
gulp.task("babel", function () {
  return gulp.src("src/**/*.js")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(concat("all.js")) // << First concat
    .pipe(browserify({      // << Then browserify
      transform:['babelify']
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```